# Is there a way to get a query to only return results based on the value returned by a case statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I'd like to get all the employees who were in a team during the date range I specify. Here's a query I tried:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN employee_team.joined <= '2019-05-01' 
and '2019-05-31' <= employee_team.left 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InTeamAtTime
FROM employee_team
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = employee_team.employee_id
WHERE InTeamAtTime = 1
ORDER BY first_name
```

I got an error message saying 
`ERROR:  column "inteamattime" does not exist` which I guess makes sense since that column doesn't actually exist in any of the tables I'm working with. But in that case how should I go about making sure my result only returns employees who were in a team within the date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For column aliases which are defined in the select-list (including aliases to expressions) you can't reference them in the WHERE clause by that alias, as they don't "exist yet" at that point.  You could copy the expression into the WHERE clause.  But actually you could *move* it to the WHERE clause, as there is no point in keeping it in the select-list just to return a column of all '1's.

If for some reason you want to reference the expression in both places, but don't want to repeat the text, you could wrap your select in another select.  At that point the inner-query's alias becomes available to an outer query's WHERE.

```
select * from (
    SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN employee_team.joined <= '2019-05-01' 
    and '2019-05-31' <= employee_team.left 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InTeamAtTime
    FROM employee_team
    INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = employee_team.employee_id
) foobar
WHERE InTeamAtTime = 1
ORDER BY first_name
```

Also, your CASE statement could be trivially written directly as a boolean expression, but I'll assume you actually want something more complicated there.

Comment: How would I go about writing it as a boolean expression?

Comment: It already is one, as that is what CASE WHEN expects.  It is just needlessly wrapped in a CASE, which converts from boolean to 1 or 0.  So just `employee_team.joined <= '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31' <= employee_team.left`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot repeat a column alias in the `where`.  A handy method is to use a lateral join:

```
SELECT et.*, e.*, v.InTeamAtTime
FROM employee_team et INNER JOIN
     employee e
     ON e.id = et.employee_id CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES ( (et.joined <= '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' <= et.left)::int )
     ) v_InTeamAtTime
WHERE v.InTeamAtTime = 1
ORDER BY e.first_name;
```

Alternative are a subquery, CTE, or repeat the expression.

Of course, in your case you could just do:

```
SELECT et.*, e.*, 1 as InTeamAtTime
FROM employee_team et INNER JOIN
     employee e
     ON e.id = et.employee_id 
WHERE et.joined <= '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' <= et.left
ORDER BY e.first_name;
```